# Efficient numpy cosine distance calculation

Tags: python, numpy

I want to calculate the nearest cosine neighbors of a vector using the rows of a matrix, and have been testing the performance of a few Python functions for doing this.

```
def cos_loop_spatial(matrix, vector):
    """
    Calculating pairwise cosine distance using a common for loop with the numpy cosine function.
    """
    neighbors = []
    for row in range(matrix.shape[0]):
        neighbors.append(scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(vector, matrix[row,:]))
    return neighbors

def cos_loop(matrix, vector):
    """
    Calculating pairwise cosine distance using a common for loop with manually calculated cosine value.
    """
    neighbors = []
    for row in range(matrix.shape[0]):
        vector_norm = np.linalg.norm(vector)
        row_norm = np.linalg.norm(matrix[row,:])
        cos_val = vector.dot(matrix[row,:]) / (vector_norm * row_norm)
        neighbors.append(cos_val)
    return neighbors

def cos_matrix_multiplication(matrix, vector):
    """
    Calculating pairwise cosine distance using matrix vector multiplication.
    """
    dotted = matrix.dot(vector)
    matrix_norms = np.linalg.norm(matrix, axis=1)
    vector_norm = np.linalg.norm(vector)
    matrix_vector_norms = np.multiply(matrix_norms, vector_norm)
    neighbors = np.divide(dotted, matrix_vector_norms)
    return neighbors

cos_functions = [cos_loop_spatial, cos_loop, cos_matrix_multiplication]

# Test performance and plot the best results of each function
mat = np.random.randn(1000,1000)
vec = np.random.randn(1000)
cos_performance = {}
for func in cos_functions:
    func_performance = %timeit -o func(mat, vec)
    cos_performance[func.__name__] = func_performance.best

pd.Series(cos_performance).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: result]

The `cos_matrix_multiplication` function is clearly the fastest of these, but I'm wondering if you have suggestions of further efficiency improvements for matrix vector cosine distance calculations.

Comment: What was your test case?

Answer (score 18):

1. Your code does not run: there are missing `import` statements:

   ```
   import numpy as np
   import scipy.spatial.distance
   ```
2. Your algorithms compute different results, so some of them must be wrong!

   ```
   >>> vector = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
   >>> matrix = np.array([[7, 5, 8, 1, 9], [6, 6, 4, 0, 8]])
   >>> cos_matrix_multiplication(matrix, vector)
   array([ 0.81818182,  0.76558762])
   >>> cos_loop(matrix, vector)
   [0.81818181818181823, 0.76558761870466252]
   >>> cos_loop_spatial(matrix, vector)
   [0.18181818181818177, 0.23441238129533748]
   ```

   In `cos_matrix_multiplication` and `cos_loop`, you've forgotten to subtract the distance from 1. In what follows I have fixed these bugs.
3. Your graph. (i) It has a very poor "[data-ink ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Tufte#Information_design)": just three data points! (ii) We can't actually read off the data points in any case, only estimate them based on the length of the bars; (iii) The labels are hard to read because they are written vertically; (iv) I can't copy and paste the labels, let alone the data. A better way to present this kind of information is in a table, like the one I give below.
4. You hint in the text that your *real* problem is to do with finding nearest neighbours. It's always best to ask about your real problem rather than some proxy for it. We might be able to suggest a solution that involves a different approach. (For example, if you were using Euclidean distance rather than cosine distance, it might make sense to use [`scipy.spatial.KDTree`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html). But we can't help you unless you tell us what you're really trying to do.)
5. Scipy includes a function [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) specifically for computing pairwise distances. In your case you could call it like this:

   ```
   def cos_cdist(matrix, vector):
       """
       Compute the cosine distances between each row of matrix and vector.
       """
       v = vector.reshape(1, -1)
       return scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(matrix, v, 'cosine').reshape(-1)
   ```
6. You don't give us your test case, so I can't confirm your findings or compare them against my own implementation. For example, how many dimensions do your points typically have? I used the following test case:

   ```
   import timeit

   def test():
       algorithms = (cos_loop_spatial, cos_loop, cos_matrix_multiplication,
                     cos_cdist)
       vector = np.random.rand(10)
       matrix = np.random.rand(100000, 10)
       for algorithm in algorithms:
           t = timeit.timeit(lambda:algorithm(matrix, vector), number=1)
           print("{:30s} {:f}".format(algorithm.__name__, t))
   ```

   Which produces the following results:

   ```
   cos_loop_spatial               8.231966
   cos_loop                       7.212096
   cos_matrix_multiplication      0.106005
   cos_cdist                      0.019018
   ```

   So `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` is about five times as fast (on this test case) as `cos_matrix_multiplication`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments, you're absolutely right about everything. My test case is in the context of distributional semantic modeling using a simple collocation matrix. This usually lead to at least 100.000 dimensions of sparse vectors. I will modify my code according to your suggestions.