# Cosine similarity computation

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, clustering, scipy

I have a matrix of ~4.5 million vector [4.5mil, 300] and I want to calculate the distance between a vector of length 300 against all the entries in the matrix.

I got some great performance time using the answers from the following post: [Efficient numpy cosine distance calculation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55717/efficient-numpy-cosine-distance-calculation).

```
from scipy import spatial


def cos_matrix_multiplication(vector, matrix):

    v = vector.reshape(1, -1)
    scores=spatial.distance.cdist(matrix_1, v, 'cosine').reshape(-1)
    return scores
```

Here, `vector` is a NumPy array [300,1] and `matrix_1` is a NumPy matrix [4.5mil, 300]

Using this I can calculate scores for the entire matrix (4.5 mil records) in about 19secs. I have been trying to optimize it even further but don't seem to make any progress.

I want to know if it is feasible to convert this code into a cython code or use Process/Thread pool to speed up even more.

I split my matrix into smaller chunks (500K each) and used `ThreadPoolExecutor` as follows:

```
matrix_list=[mat_small1,mat_small2,....,mat_small9]

import concurrent.futures
def cos_thread():
    neighbors=[]

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:

        future_to_list = {executor.submit(cos_matrix_multiplication,vec,mat_col): mat_col for mat_col in matrix_list}

        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_list):

            data = future.result()

            neighbors.extend(data)

    return neighbors
```

I can currently compute the entire ~4.5 million `cosines` in ~5 seconds.

Comment: Work through `cython` tutorials.  And study the internals of `cdist`  You can't just throw your code at `cython`.

Comment: If you can split the matrix into parts, throw it on a multiprocessing pool?

Answer (score 2):

Does `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` run multiple cores in parallel on your machine ?
On my mac with Accelerate framework, it runs all 4 cores, 
but equivalent numpy seems to run only 1.
(This is regardless of `VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS`, which I don't understand.)

If the big matrix doesn't change very often, normalize it once outside the loop:

```
A /= np.linalg.norm( A, axis=1 )  # <-- once

def cosdist( A, b, dtype=np.float32 ):
    """ (A . b) / |b| -- A normalized """
    Adotb = A.dot(b) / 
    Adotb /= np.linalg.norm(b)
    return Adotb
```

Since `A.dot(b)` and `norm(A)` take roughly the same time,
this runs about twice as fast -- on 1 core.

How much memory do you have ? 1M x 300 x 8 bytes is 2.4 Gbytes,
which may be a reasonable chunk size; 4.5M, 11Gbytes, will be memory-bound. Can you monitor memory usage / swapping ?

Using `np.float32` instead of the default `np.float64`
*might* be faster, or allow bigger chunks.
But `scipy cdist` seems to convert float32 to float64, slower.

Numpy and scipy link to libraries for
[BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms),
Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms.
These libs are usually vendor-tuned, faster than C or Cython loops.
To see what numpy / scipy link to:

```
from numpy import __config__
print "numpy blas:\n", __config__.get_info( "blas_opt" )

from scipy import __config__
print "scipy blas:\n", __config__.get_info( "blas_opt" )
```

Even though these are the same (Accelerate framework on my mac),
numpy and scipy have different wrappers around BLAS
(`numpy/linalg/linalg/lapack_lite.so`, `scipy/linalg/cython_blas.so`)
with different overheads.

Summary: numpy / scipy `dot` and `norm` to BLAS
to multiple cores is a messy business.
Don't trust any runtimes that you haven't run yourself.